# How to inform audiounit host, that kAudioUnitProperty_Latency has changed?

Tags: core-audio, audiounit

my AudioUnits are working just fine, but when the latency has changed, they need to inform host about it. Here's my code:

```
AudioUnitEvent e;
MMEMSET(&e, 0, sizeof(AudioUnitEvent));
e.mArgument.mProperty.mAudioUnit = Instance;//GetComponentInstance ();
e.mArgument.mProperty.mPropertyID = kAudioUnitProperty_Latency;
e.mArgument.mProperty.mScope = kAudioUnitScope_Global;
e.mArgument.mProperty.mElement = 0;
e.mEventType = kAudioUnitEvent_PropertyChange;
AUEventListenerNotify (paramListenerRef, NULL, &e);
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to do anything in most hosts, especially Logic. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it. So, you need to manage list of property listeners, and whenever this happens ask all property listeners. Ugly, but I spent some time looking into the horrible CoreAudio SDK and that's how they do it...